# WebStorm SCSS file watcher encoding error

Tags: encoding, sass, webstorm, file-watcher

The file watcher worked fine at first, but now I get this output everytime it runs:

```
cmd.exe /D /C call scss.bat -E UTF-8 --no-cache --update components.scss:components.css
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: GBK and UTF-8
  Use --trace for backtrace.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The file encoding was definately `UTF-8` and if I excute the same command manually through `cmd.exe` I get the scss file transpiled successfully.
How can I solve this? Thx.

Comment: what is the file encoding in WebStorm? Check the encoding shown in lower right corner when the file is loaded in editor

Comment: @lena i double checked that it was `UTF-8`, and if that's the problem then I wouldn't have it transpiled through `cmd.exe`

Comment: Do you have any non-ASCII characters in path to your project?

Comment: @lena yes, but that DID work at first. Now I solved this problem indirectly by creating a new project (which shares the same root directory with the previous one).

Comment: it's a known ruby issue - encoding errors are usually thrown in case of non-ascii characters in path/user profile name/etc.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem - turns out that local chars in project path caused problem. So if you have any local/national/diacritic characters in a project path change them.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You saved the day! Thank you :)